# Nodejs: simple code works on local but not on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I am still learning node but there's one thing that I can't find answers anywhere.
I am trying to deploy a simple code to read the content of a URL. It works fine on localhost but when I deploy to my azure app it does not work at all.
When I access the link on the browser it shows a blank screen.

Here's the code

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    const url = "http://www.google.com";

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});


    http.get(url, res => {

        res.setEncoding("utf8");
        let body = "";
        res.on("data", data => {
            body += data;
        });

        res.on("end", () => {

        console.log("End of response", port);

        response.end('End of response.<br/>');

        });


    });

});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
server.listen(port);

console.log("Server running at http://localhost:%d", port);
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you are executing your server file on the server?

Comment: Do you have npm, node installed on your azure machine? Did you install the npm packages on said machine?

Comment: There are so many things that can go wrong
1. Have you exposed the port (1337 or env port) so that a request can reach your server? Look at the logs to see that
2.  Is your server running? Look at the logs
3. Open the browser dev tools, what is the response you are getting?

Comment: Hi guys thabks for the replies. When I remove the http.get it works fine. The app shows my message on the browser. So I think node is working fine. Is there a way to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

> When I access the link on the browser it shows a blank screen.

I encountered the similar issue before, I tried to access `http://cn.bing.com`, but the request would be automatically redirected to `https` and there is no any response content.

Based on your code, I created my azure web app to check this issue.

**app.js:**

```html
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

    http.get("http://www.google.com", res => {

        //check the status code
        console.log(res.statusCode+','+res.headers['location']);

        res.setEncoding("utf8");
        let body = "";
        res.on("data", data => {
            body += data;
        });

        res.on("end", () => {
        console.log("End of response", port);
        response.end(body);
        });

    }).on('error',(e)=>{ //catch the error 
        console.error('Got error:'+e);
        response.end('Got exception:'+e);
    });

});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
server.listen(port);

console.log("Server running at http://localhost:%d", port);
```

My project contents look like this via [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/).

[image]

**TEST:**

[image]

For verifying the logs, you could [Enable diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) and check your application logs. Also, you could add a `iisnode.yml` file into your web app root folder and specific your log configurations, details you could follow [Debug Node.js Web Apps on Azure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/08/19/debug-node-js-web-apps-on-azure/).

Additionally, here are some related tutorials, you could refer to them:

[http.get(options[, callback])](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)

[How to deploy a node.js site into Azure Web App to create a Website](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/laurelle/2015/12/01/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-site-into-azure-web-app-to-create-a-website/)

[Create a Node.js web app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs)

Comment: Even if it was redirected shouldnt the app output my generic message? Like I said it works fine on my localhost.

Comment: I just provided the similar issue I encountered before, for your scenario, it could work on my azure web app. Your code only output the result under `res.on("end"`, I would suggest you log the `res` under your `http.get` and try to catch the error under `http.get` as the code I provided to troubleshoot this issue.